# using ngFor in-line for json array

Tags: json, angular

I do 99% back end stuff... but I took an Angular class a while ago, don't remember much but I do remember looping over arrays of JSON objects using `ngFor` ...

Anyway, I need a quick proof of concept for something I'm working on, and could use the ability to generate an in-line JS variable full of JSON via PHP and then iterate through that collection/array.

I can generate the JSON and bring it in as a variable.  And I can address parts of it.  But I cannot seem to get `ngFor` (or `*ngFor`) to loop over the object.

No errors are generated.  Any test output I try to generate by specifically addressing the data array, or a specific object in it, or a specific property of a specific object work fine.

Knowing my Angular background and skills, I'm betting it is a simple syntax thing with how I'm trying to invoke the `ngFor`, or perhaps there is a different/better function I should be using - but I've checked several different tutorials and it is basically a copy/paste of what they are all doing.

I know I can dig out my old homework and do it all as an AngularCLI thing, but that is way overkill for what I need to do, and I really really don't want to go down that path.

Help?

JSON file -

```
[{"room":"chat","text":"woo bie woobie woo","user":"AnonymousCoward","timestamp":1536423020}, 
{"room":"chat","text":"who are you","user":"AnonymousCoward","timestamp":1536423022},
{"room":"chat","text":"where am i?","user":"AnonymousCoward","timestamp":1536423025}
]
```

Code -

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("data.json");
// clean up formatting for when i print it in-line
// for js to pick up
$data = json_encode(json_decode($data));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.data = JSON.parse('<?php print($data); ?>');
                // this prints the json string for
                // the 0th element as a string or 
                // the text property of a specific
                // element w/o error, etc
                 var d=$scope.data[0];
                 console.log(d);
                 console.log(d.text);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <ul>
                <!-- generates expected output -->
                <li>{{data[0].text}}</li>
                <!-- following does not work - but no errors -->
                <li *ngFor="let datum of $scope.data;let i=index">
                    {{i}} {{datum.room}}    
                </li>
                <!-- neither does this - but still no errors -->
                <li *ngFor="let datum of data;let i=index">
                    {{i}} {{datum.room}}    
                </li>
                <!-- and using *ngFor vs just ngFor doesn't 
                seem to make a difference either -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <pre><?php print_r(json_decode($data)); ?></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `*ngFor` is for Angular 2+. You are using AngularJS (1.x).

Comment: Use `ng-repeat` since you're using AngularJS

Comment: @PankajParkar thank you, that works.  Figured I was calling something wrong, and since HTML attributes don't throw errors...   Please post it as an answer so I can accept and give you the credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using AngularJS not Angular. In AngularJS (1.x) for repeating and rendering same template multiple times use `ng-repeat` directive

Use `ng-repeat` directive instead of `*ngFor`

```
ng-repeat="datum in data"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller code looks like with Angularjs, use angularjs syntax ng-repeat as follows,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <ul>
                <!-- generates expected output -->
                <li>{{data[0].text}}</li>
                <!-- following does not work - but no errors -->
                <li ng-repeat="datum in data;let i=index">
                    {{i}} {{datum.room}}    
                </li>
                <!-- neither does this - but still no errors -->
                <li ng-repeat="datum in data;let i=index">
                    {{i}} {{datum.room}}    
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  If @PankajParkar doesn't post his comment as an answer I can accept, then I will accept yours.